# Trasition doesn't work with addClass and RemoveClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like when scrolling container, my menu change her heigth, width and hide her title, I  have got it but don't work the transition that I added.

html:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {

  $("#container-wrapper").scroll(function() {
    if ($('#container-wrapper').scrollTop() > 25) {
      $('#list-menu').addClass('down');
    } else {
      $('#list-menu').removeClass('down');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#list-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#list-menu.down li {
  width: 90px;
  height: 38px;
}

#list-menu.down li a span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=list-menu>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
      <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Repeat, the script works, but don't do the transition! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the working code.

Comment: transition only works with numbers value (it breaks the value  into bits to make the transition) . If want a transition from none to block, then there is only one step possible ! you may try opacity :0 to opacity:1

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the updated code and updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/bilaleme90/pen/wrvdoW)

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {

$( "#container-wrapper" ).scroll(function() {
  if($('#container-wrapper').scrollTop() > 25){
    $('#list-menu').addClass('down');
  }else{
    $('#list-menu').removeClass('down');
  }

});
  
});
```

```css
#list-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;

   -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:         all 0.3s ease-out;

}
.down li{
    width: 90px;
    height: 38px;
}
.down li a span{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=list-menu>
    <div class="container" id="container-wrapper" style="height:400px; overflow:auto;">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="default.asp"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu">Empleado</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Citas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Facturación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Estadísticas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="title-menu"><span>Campañas</span></a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
```

The code is running as per your requirement now

Comment: the problem with the title is solved, thanks but the list when I do to scroll still without work..what can I do?

Comment: @jlgf your code is missing the .container-wrapper and cannot show your issue . we can only go for a guess. transition must happen on which rule ? if it is display, read my earlier comment , it will not work, You have to use another rule/method

Comment: @jlgf Now i have understood your problem. I did couple of changes to the same code pen. you were assigning #list-menu the class .down and in the css you mentioned #list-menu.down which was not correct. Another thing is that you didn't have the container-wrapper id mentioned in the html document. 

I am editting the above answer and the codepen kindly refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transition on the li's, not the '#list-menu'.
Also for width and height to animate, you need initial values for it

Comment: @farhad How does this not answer the question? The problem was that the transitions didn't work, and I pointed out why

Comment: I did the transition on the li's and nothing friend

Comment: @jlgf did you add initial values on those li's for width and height? It's not gonna work without it. It needs to have values from which to transition from

Comment: yes I did, don't understand why still without work, i saw example on internet and work perfectly..

Comment: @jlgf here is a short sample: [link](https://codepen.io/stonefmagiecurata/pen/GMRvea)